# Flink stream order

Tags: java, apache-flink

Does Flink guarantee the order of execution of a stream?

I have two Kafka topics (each with single partition), stream 1 and stream 2, and use `keyBy`, the streams are processed by a `coprocess` function.

During my testing I can see the the contents of both streams are not always executed in order.

I can set parallelism to 1 to get around this issue, but wanted to understand if what I am seeing is what is expected?

```
source1.keyBy(e -> e.f0);
source2.keyBy(e -> {
    return new JSONObject(e.f1).getString("someOtherKey");
});

source1.connect(source2)
       .process(new KeyedCoProcessFunction())
       .uid("uid")
       .name("name");
```

Answer (score 4):

Events will maintain their relative ordering *if they take the same path through the execution graph*. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Here's an example of what can happen with a `keyBy`. Initally the events are ordered as 1, 2, A

[image]

but a `keyBy` sends A down a different path than 1 and 2:

[image]

after which we might see A, 1, 2 (as shown here), or 1, A, 2, or 1, 2, A.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Are these images from the Flink documentation? If so, which page is it?

Comment: No, I lifted those images from the Flink training materials.