# Flink - take advantage of input partitioning to avoid inter task-manager communications

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

We have a Flink pipeline aggregating data per "client" by combining data with identical keys ("client-id") and within the same window.

The problem is trivially parallelizable and the input Kafka topic has a few partitions (same number as the Flink parallelism) - each holding a subset of the clients. I.e., **a single client is always in a specific Kafka partition**.

**Does Flink take advantage of this automatically or will reshuffle the keys?** And if the latter is true - can we somehow avoid the reshuffle and keep the data local to each operator as assigned by the input partitioning?

Note: we are actually using Apache Beam with the Flink backend but I tried to simplify the question as much as possible. Beam is using `FixedWindows` followed by `Combine.perKey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the internals of the Flink runner for Beam, but assuming it is using a Flink `keyBy`, then this will involve a network shuffle. This could be avoided, but only rather painfully by reimplementing the job to use low-level Flink primitives, rather than keyed windows and keyed state.

Flink does offer `reinterpretAsKeyedStream`, which can be used to avoid unnecessary shuffles, but this can only applied in situations where the existing partitioning exactly matches what keyBy would do -- and I see no reason to think that would apply here.

Comment: Assuming I control the input Kafka partitioning. Can you give any pointers as to how I should define it to match what keyBy would produce? 

Thanks for mentioning reinterpretAsKeyedStream! Beam doesn't support that but this does look like what we need here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69802568/2000823 for the mapping from keys to slots. The kafka source does a round-robin assignment of partitions to slots. That should be enough to compute which partition to use for each key.